# Could not click on button org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:</button> is not clickable at point (502, 85). Other element would receive the click:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Angular Js application. And auotmating using selenium and Java.Whenever I try clicking on on button getting exception as.

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button .</button> is not clickable at point (502, 85). Other element would receive the click: <div class="col-sm-12 move-buttons">...</div>
```

Tried many option but none worked. Any solution is welcomed. 
Thanks in Advance.!!
**This is the div which looks like**

```
    <div class="col-sm-1">
<div class="row zhide-buttons" xpath="1"> 
  <div class="col-sm-12 move-buttons"> 
   class="btn btn-primary move-button ng-scope" ng-disabled=""> <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i> </button><!-- end ngIf: 

   <i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x"></i> </button>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

I tried using with xpath
1.//div[contains(@class,'col-sm-1')]//button[1]
2.//i[@class='fa fa-plus fa-2x']
3.using the x,y coordainate using **Action Class**

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'col-sm-1')]//button[1]")));

**Here is my sample code**

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'col-sm-1')]//button[1]"));

js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Also I tried normal locating element and clicking onto it.
This also gives same error.

**So ultimately I am not able to click on this button**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Action Class -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By("element"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

or

```
WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath"));((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo("+elementToClick.getLocation().x+","+elementToClick.getLocation().y+")"); elementToClick.click();
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIME_IN_SECONDS);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("element-class-name")));
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. code worked for me using code snippet below 
  .js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(1000,document.body.scrollHeight)");
 
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 
 
 WebElement addXYZ = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-plus fa-2x']"));
 JavascriptExecutor jse2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse2.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", addXYZ);